# Flatten table in Excel using VBA

Tags: database, vba, excel, transformation

I'm looking to use VBA to transform a raw data extract into a flattened table for querying. Currently, I have a raw data table in Excel that summarizes the status of Phases A, B, and C for a given Engagement (note: some Engagements may not have data for all 3 phases).

```
Row| EngagementID | A_date | A_status | B_date | B_status | C_date | C_status
1  |      201     |   2/2  | Approved |        |          |        |          
2  |      201     |        |          |  3/5   | Approved |        |          
3  |      201     |        |          |        |          |  4/1   |  Pending  
4  |      203     |   2/12 | Submitted|        |          |        |          
5  |      203     |        |          |  2/20  | Approved |        |          
6  |      207     |   2/5  | Approved |        |          |        |
```

I need to flatten the table to look like something this:

```
Row| EngagementID | Date | Status 
1  |      201     |  2/2 | Approved 
2  |      201     |  3/5 | Approved          
3  |      201     |  4/1 | Pending  
4  |      203     |  2/12| Submitted         
5  |      203     |  2/20| Approved          
6  |      207     |  2/5 | Approved
```

Additionally, I'd like to add a column for the Phase so that I can "tag" each row with the Phase (A, B, or C) that it is associated with.

I've tried the following VBA code, but it flattens the table vertically, as opposed to horizontally (merging 3 rows into 1, as opposed to 3 columns into 1):

```
Private Sub test()
Dim R As Long
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
R = 2
Count = 0
Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & R))
    If Cells(R, 1).Value = Cells(R + 1, 1).Value Then
        Count = Count + 1
    Else
        i = 1
        Do While i <= Count
            Cells(R - Count, 2 + (2 * i)).Value = Cells(R - Count + i, 2 + (2 * i))
            Cells(R - Count, 3 + (2 * i)).Value = Cells(R - Count + i, 3 + (2 * i))
            i = i + 1
        Loop
            i = 1
            Do While i <= Count
                Rows(R - Count + i).Delete
                i = i + 1
                R = R - 1
            Loop
        Count = 0
    End If
R = R + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Please help!!

Comment: You could transpose the VBA so that, for example, `Cells(R, 1)` becomes `Cells(1, R)` and so on. also instead of manipulating rows, you'll need to manipulate columns Or, if this is a one shot, transpose the table and run the macro on it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a           As Variant
Dim b           As Variant
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long
Dim k           As Long

a = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1) * 3, 1 To 3)

For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
    For j = 2 To UBound(a, 2) Step 2
        If a(i, j) <> "" And a(i, j + 1) <> "" Then
            k = k + 1
            b(k, 1) = a(i, 1)
            b(k, 2) = a(i, j)
            b(k, 3) = a(i, j + 1)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Range("J1").Resize(k, UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
End Sub
```